# Mask-RCNN project Kangaroo learning example facing problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

**[Mask-RCNN-TF2](https://github.com/ahmedfgad/Mask-RCNN-TF2)**

I am trying to learn mrcnn. When I run this kangaroo training code this flowing filepath  Mask-RCNN-TF2-master\kangaroo-transfer-learning/kangaroo_training.py

I am facing an error in kangaroo_training.py file in line no 103.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzTcF.png)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:/Thisis/Object Detection/Mask-RCNN-TF2-master/kangaroo-transfer-learning/kangaroo_training.py", line 108, in 
layers='heads')

File "G:\Thisis\Object Detection\Mask-RCNN-TF2-master\kangaroo-transfer-learning\mrcnn\model.py", line 2347, in train
os.makedirs(self.log_dir)

File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)

File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)

File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '//'

Process finished with exit code 1

NOTE: i follow step that readme file  says

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a "path" error to the "log" directory. In the Mask-RCNN-TF2 the `log` directory is not under Kangaroo. Lock in `Kangaroo_config()` to the `path` to `log`